# Content has strange reflect to animating with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am using animate.css with this jQuery code to animate my content when loaded and when a specific button pushed .

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".next").addClass("animated fadeInRightArrow")},4800);
```

I am using this sample line of code with some another to animate the content , I have 2 sections , About and Services .
When the page is loaded , About section objects will start to fading in ,
And when "A" button is clicked , About objects will start to fadeOut and Services objects will fadeIn in queue .
Then , when "B" button is clicked, Services objects will start to fadeOut and About elements should fadeIn again in queue .
But it's not as expected , The About objects will appear for a second and disappear again .
I don't know if I explained the problem obviously ...
take a look at jquery I use :

```
<script>

        $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$(".logo").addClass("animated logoFade")},2100);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline").addClass("animated fadeInUp")},2400);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline2").addClass("animated headlineFade")},2800);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#abtn").addClass("animated fadeInDown")},3200);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#csbtn").addClass("animated fadeInDown")},3500);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".up").addClass("animated fadeInDownArrow")},3900);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".prev").addClass("animated fadeInLeftArrow")},4200);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".down").addClass("animated fadeInUpArrow")},4500);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".next").addClass("animated fadeInRightArrow")},4800);
})
    </script>

        <script>

        $("#csbtn").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline").addClass("animated fadeOutUp")},100);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline2").addClass("animated headlineFadeOut")},500);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#abtn").addClass("animated fadeOutDown")},700);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#csbtn").addClass("animated fadeOutDown")},1100);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".clock-section").css("display","block")},1500);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#home").css("display","none")},1900);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#clock-title").addClass("animated fadeIn")},1900);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#clock").addClass("animated fadeIn")},2200);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#homebtn").addClass("animated fadeInUp")},2400);


});
    </script>
               <script>

        $("#homebtn").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$("#clock-title").addClass("animated fadeOutUp")},100);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#clock").addClass("animated fadeOut")},300);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#homebtn").addClass("animated fadeOutDown")},600);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".clock-section").css("display","none")},1500);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#home").css("display","block")},1900);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline").addClass("animated fadeInUp")},900);
        setTimeout(function(){$("#headline2").addClass("animated headlineFade")},1300);


});
    </script>
```

Can someone explains where I am wrong ? 
It really gets on my nerves ...
Thanks a lot ! :)
P.S : you can take a look at Animate.css here if required : [Animate.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for us to better help you?

Comment: @tllewellyn the project is very complicated but I'll try if I can make a jsfiddle

Comment: wow! too many `.setTimeout` calls. pretty sure it can be optimised and there can be a better way to approach this problem. let us know when you have made the fiddle.